# In a "i < vector.size()" loop condition, is size() called each iteration?

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-optimization, stdvector, loop-invariant

In the following code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> var;
for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++);
```

Is the `size()` member function called for each loop iteration, or only once?

Comment: Have you measured a difference or looked at the output?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to measure it is there a reference I can read ? or search keywords

Comment: It should be noted that using the std algorithms help the compiler optimize as they separate the looping code from generation of the range. `std::for_each(var.begin(), var.end(), Action());`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

*In theory*, it is called each time, since a for loop:

```
for(initialization; condition; increment)
    body;
```

is expanded to something like

```
{
    initialization;
    while(condition)
    {
        body;
        increment;
    }
}
```

(notice the curly braces, because initialization is already in an inner scope)

*In practice*, if the compiler understands that a piece of your condition is invariant through all the duration of the loop and *it does not have side-effects*, it can be smart enough to move it out. This is routinely done with `strlen` and things like that (that the compiler knows well) in loops where its argument isn't written.

However it must be noted that this last condition isn't always trivial to prove; in general, it's easy if the container is local to the function and is never passed to external functions; if the container is not local (e.g. it's passed by reference - even if it's `const`) and the loop body contains calls to other functions, the compiler often has to assume that such functions may alter it, thus blocking the hoisting of the length calculation.

Doing that optimization by hand is worthy if you know that a part of your condition is "expensive" to evaluate (and such condition usually isn't, since it usually boils down to a pointer subtraction, which is almost surely inlined).

---

**Edit:** as others said, in general with containers it's better to use iterators, but for `vector`s it's not so important, because random access to elements via `operator[]` is guaranteed to be O(1); actually with vectors it usually is a pointer sum (vector base+index) and dereference vs the pointer *increment* (preceding element+1) and dereference of iterators. Since the target address is still the same, I don't think that you can gain something from iterators in terms of cache locality (and even if so, if you're not walking big arrays in tight loops you shouldn't even notice such kind of improvements).

For lists and other containers, instead, using iterators instead of random access can be *really* important, since using random access may mean walk every time the list, while incrementing an iterator is just a pointer dereference.

Comment: Actually... shouldn't the increment be inside the while loop?

Comment: "if you're manipulating a vector via a const reference, the compiler can exploit this information to be sure that its fields will never change". Not unless the vector object itself (not just the reference) is const. If you call code that could potentially modify the vector through an alias, then the compile cannot optimise even if *your* reference is const. If you don't call to unknown code, then the compiler is allowed to optimise even if your reference is non-const.

Comment: use size_t instead of vector<int>::size_type since by reference it need to be the same, and the latter will deprecated in C++17

Comment: @user3063349: actually, I'll remove that paragraph altogether, since when I wrote this answer I changed my mind about `size_t` as an index - in general, it's just more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @MatteoItalia 
what you mean about "more hassle" , you wanna mention that we should use int instead?

Answer (score 12):

The `size()` member function is called each time, but it would be a really bad implementation that wouldn't inline it, and a strange one where it wouldn't be a simple access of a fixed datum or a subtraction of two pointers.
Anyway, you shouldn't worry yourself with such trivialities until you have profiled your application and found out that this is a bottleneck.

However, what you *should* pay attention to is:

1. The correct type for a vector's index is `std::vector<T>::size_type`.
2. There are types (some iterators, for example) where `i++` *might* be slower than `++i`.

Therefore, the loop should be:

```
for(vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<var.size(); ++i)
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

It's 'called' each time, but I put called into quotes because it really probably is just an inline method call, so you don't have to worry about its performance.

Why not use `vector<int>::iterator` instead?

Comment: "vector<int>::iterator" is a lot more verbose than "int" -- without providing any real value.  Although, as written, the OP probably gets a signed/unsigned comparison warning with int vs. vector<int>::size_type.

Comment: @nobar: I think iterators provide massive benefits with zero down side. I am sorry you feel that typing a few characters as a burden. Since the whole STL is based on iterators learning to use them correctly is a nessesty.

Comment: @Martin: The C++ standards committee is also sorry, which is why they've provided range-based for in C++0x as a replacement for many cases of `for_each` and the other very simple algorithms. Except I think their sympathy is more sincere ;-p

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Not being argumentative but any reference to why they think iterators were bad? I see Iterators as a step forward (not a perfect step but a step). After a decade of using we now understand the problems better and have a better understanding of the strengths (and weaknesses) of iterators. The range concept is just another step that is built on-top of iterators, I don;t see them as a replacement I see them as an extension of the basic underlying concept.

Comment: I was hoping that concepts would have made it into the standard as this (by my understanding (though I have not read up on why (because was dropped))) would have made iterators easier to extend and use and debug.

Comment: I almost forget. The standards committee agreeds with @nobar that too much typing was arduous on us poor underpaid developers and introduced the 'auto' type concept (to increase our pay per keystroke by reducing the number of key strokes required).

Comment: @Martin: Good point about the use of "auto" -- that should simplify the use of iterators in the future.  Also, I don't disagree that iterators are useful for many purposes, but I write a lot of for loops that iterate over vectors and I happen to prefer the indexed approach in most cases.  One reason might be that I don't want to type so much, but a bigger reason is probably that I don't want to have to read it.  Also, the accessor syntax is different depending on which approach you take -- so that's another thing to consider when deciding which way to go.

Comment: @nobar: I agree with not wanting to type or read it. That is why I nearly always (99% of the time) use a std::algorithm that will do the looping for me.

Comment: @Martin: I don't mean they've renounced iterators, just that they genuinely are sorry that typing a few characters is such a burden. Ranged-based for is pretty much just to reduce code, regardless of whether you were previously using the equivalent loop, or the equivalent `for_each`. Of course Alexandrescu specifically does think that "something, somewhere, went terribly wrong" with iterators, and that ranges should replace the concept, not extend it. But then in a sense he's a C++ "deserter" anyway.

Comment: @Martin: I think it depends on the type of software that you are developing. For me, most of my vectors are not containers of "objects", but just large arrays of simple data (such as image pixels). Most of the for loops that I write are part of a custom algorithm that I am writing, and it seems to me that using std::for_each() would be much more cumbersome for my particular purposes -- especially, since I typically use the index value to also access neighboring pixels.

Comment: ...Also, most of the people that I work with don't know the first thing about STL (they have other domains of expertise of course), so overuse would just needlessly confuse them.  This fact also makes me glad that there are people on StackOverflow for me to converse with about this stuff. :)

Comment: @nobar: anyway my implementation of `<algorithm>` uses loops in preference to implementing everything on top of `for_each`, and I don't see why I shouldn't too :-)

Comment: @Steve: Right on!  I took a peek at <algorithm> for GNU C++.  It uses lots of loops and lots and lots of iterators.  Of course STL algorithms support various containers, so they *have* to use iterators.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your question is that it does not make any sense. A C++ compiler translates some source code into a binary program. The requirement is that the resulting program must preserve **observable effects** of the code according to the rules of the C++ Standard. This code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++);
```

simply does not have any observable effect. Moreover, it does not interact with the surrounding code any way, and the compiler may optimize it completely away; that is to generate no corresponding assembly.

To make your question meaningful, you need to specify **what happens inside the loop**. The problem with

```
for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++) { ... }
```

is that the answer very much depends on what `...` actually is. I believe @MatteoItalia provided a very nice answer, just would add a description of some experiments I made. Consider the following code:

```
int g(std::vector<int>&, size_t);

int f(std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}
```

First, even if calling `var.size()` will almost 100% sure be inlined with enabled optimizations, and this inlining typically translates into a subtraction of two pointers, this still brings into the loop some overhead. If a compiler is not able to prove that the vector size is preserved (which, generally, is very difficult or even infeasible, such as in our case), then you will end up with unnecessary *load* and *sub* (and, possibly, *shift*) instructions. The generated assembly of the loop with GCC 9.2, `-O3`, and x64 was:

```
.L3:
    mov     rsi, rbx
    mov     rdi, rbp
    add     rbx, 1
    call    g(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned long)
    add     r12d, eax
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+8] // loads a pointer
    sub     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp+0] // subtracts another poniter
    sar     rax, 2                 // result * sizeof(int) => size()
    cmp     rbx, rax
    jb      .L3
```

If we rewrite the code as follows:

```
int g(std::vector<int>&, size_t);

int f(std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0, e = v.size(); i < e; i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}
```

then, the generated assembly is simpler (and, therefore, faster):

```
.L3:
    mov     rsi, rbx
    mov     rdi, r13
    add     rbx, 1
    call    g(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, unsigned long)
    add     r12d, eax
    cmp     rbx, rbp
    jne     .L3
```

The value of the vector's size is simply kept in a register (`rbp`).

I even tried a different version where the vector is marked as being `const`:

```
int g(const std::vector<int>&, size_t);

int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {
   int res = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      res += g(v, i);
   return res;
}
```

Surprisingly, even when `v.size()` cannot change here, the generated assembly was the same as in the first case (with additional `mov`, `sub`, and `sar` instructions).

Live demo is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jeTihg).

Additionally, when I changed the loop into:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   res += v[i];
```

then, there was no evaluation of `v.size()` (subtraction of pointers) within the loop on an assembly level. GCC was able to "see" here, that the body of the loop does not alter the size any way.

Answer (score 2):

It must be called everytime because size() might return a different value everytime.

Therefore there's no big choice it simply must be.

Comment: This answer is correct in the most general sense (the resulting code *must* behave as if it were called every time), but compiler writers work *very* hard at detecting the special cases where it can be safely factored out.

Comment: That's true ;-) However you cannot rely on this as this is compiler specific.

Answer (score 2):

But it could be done in this way (providing that this loop intends to only read/write without actually changing the size of a vector):

```
for(vector<int>::size_type i=0, size = var.size(); i < size; ++i) 
{
//do something
}
```

In the loop above you have just one call to size independently from size being inlined or not.

Answer (score 1):

As other have said

- the semantics must be as if it were called each time
- it is probably inlined, and is probably a simple function

on top of which

- a smart enough optimizer may be able to deduce that it is a loop invariant with no side effects and elide it entirely (this is easier if the code is inlined, but may be possible even if it is not *if* the compiler does global optimization)

Answer (score 1):

I **think** that if the compiler can conclusively deduce that the variable `var` is not modified inside the "loop body"

```
for(int i=0; i< var.size();i++) { 
    // loop body
}
```

then the above may be transposed to something equivalent of

```
const size_t var_size = var.size();
for( int i = 0; i < var_size; i++ ) { 
    // loop body
}
```

However, I am not absolutely sure, so comments are welcome :)

Also,

- In most situations, the `size()` member function is inlined, so the issue does not warrant worrying
- The concern is perhaps equally applicable to the `end()` which is always used for iterator based looping, i.e. `it != container.end()`
- Please consider using `size_t` or `vector<int>::size_type` for the type of `i` [See Steve Jessop's comment below.]

Comment: The return type of `std::vector<int>::size()` is `std::vector<int>::size_type`, which you would strongly expect to be the same type as `size_t`, but needn't be.

Answer (score 1):

as others said, The compiler shall decide what to do with the actual code written. The key figure is that it is called each time. But if you want to get a performance boost, it is best to write your code with some considerations. Your case is one of them, there are others as well, like the difference between these two pieces of code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
{
   for ( int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j)
       printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
   printf("\n");
}
for (int j = 0 ; j < n ; ++j)
{
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i)
       printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

The difference is that the first one will not change the ram page too much per references, but the other will exhaust your cache and TLB and other stuff.

Also *inline* won't help that much! because the order of the calling function will remain as n(size of the vector) times. It helps in some places though, but the best thing is to rewrite your code.

But! if you want to let a compiler do it's optimizations over your code NEVER put volatile, like so:

```
for(volatile int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i)
```

It prevents the compiler from optimizing.
If you need another hint for performance use register instead of volatile.

```
for(register int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i)
```

The compiler will try not to move i from the CPU-registers to RAM. It is not ensured that it can do it, but it will do it's best ;)

Comment: I can't think of any compiler where register is actually taken into consideration... the compiler will do its own register choices.

Comment: Ofcourse the inline will help... since it will probably be inlined to the size member variable, thus no function call...

Comment: Also, even though you are correct about the cache locality... it has nothing to do with the question asked...

Comment: @ronag: I guess that is the wrong idea, I did not say inline won't help, i just said rewriting the code is better. Also it is also compilers choice to inline the function or not. I just answered his question this way because i thought he was curious about how to make for loops better.

Comment: How would re-writing the code be better? Any decent compiler will make a better decision regarding these micro optimization than either of us.

Comment: Also what is register keyword made for then? C++ was making keywords to do what?

Comment: The register keyword was useful in a time when compiler optimization were not as good as today.

Comment: @Green Code: C++ didn't invent the `register` keyword, by the way, it inherited it from `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it for 900k iterations
Its taking time 43 seconds for pre-calculated size and 42 seconds for using the size() call.

If you guaranteed vector size doesn't  change in the loop, better to use pre-calculated size otherwise there is no choice and must use size().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<int> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
        v.push_back(i);

const size_t v_size = v.size();
for(int i = 0; i < v_size; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < v_size; j++)
                cout << "";

//for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
//      for(int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++)
//              cout << "";
}
```