# Efficiency of member function returning std::vector.size() in object oriented framework

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, loop-invariant

I have a class declared in `prob.h` thus:

```
struct A_s{
    int a, b;
}

class A_c{
    private:
        std::vector<A_s> vec_of_A_s;
    public:
        int vec_of_A_s_size() const{return static_cast<int>(vec_of_A_s.size());}
}
```

With `A_c A;//A is an object of class A_c`, somewhere else in my implementation `.cpp` file, I have the following line:

`for(int i = 0; i < A.vec_of_A_s_size(); i++) {...//do loop stuff}`

I KNOW from my program's design that `A.vec_of_A_s_size()` is loop invariant. However, I really want to avoid the following (it is cumbersome):

```
int sz = A.vec_of_A_s_size();
for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {...//do loop stuff}
```

Can I sufficiently and consistently rely on a compiler that a release build with optimization turned on (-O2) will not evaluate `vec_of_A_s.size()` each time?

Here is what I have already tried along with my questions:

(1) (Pleae see edit update below) Even with a debug build, with options `-fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -g -std=c++14`, looking at the disassembler output, `vec_of_A_s.size()` is evaluated only once. However, will the compiler do this optimization reliably consistently? Are there any known exceptions? Part of the reason for my skepticism and need for assurance stems from question (2) that follows.

(2)I looked at a related question on SO: [Performance issue for vector::size() in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901630/performance-issue-for-vectorsize-in-a-loop). The question there directly evaluates a vector's size in the loop like such:

`for(int i = 0; i < vec_of_A_s.size(); i++) {...//do loop stuff}`

In my case, the vector is not directly accessible. It is a private member of `A_c` and its size can only be accessed via the public member function `A.vec_of_A_s_size()`. So, there is an additional layer of indirection/redirection that has to happen within the for loop. The answers on that thread seem to suggest that the compiler will indeed optimize the loop invariant. But in the case (like above) where a vector's size is not directly and publicly available, will the compiler reliably guarantee the loop invariant optimization?

(3)In other related questions on such issues, a common answer seems to be to profile the program. If and when I do the profiling, what exactly should I be looking for to verify this specific optimization? This code is part of a larger numerical analysis code and this is definitely NOT the current bottleneck. Yet, it would be nice to know how this can be verified in a profiler. Apologies if this question (3) is too broad. I am relatively new to profiling. But do profilers allow profiling a single function, say the function that contains the `for` loop above? That way, I can know for sure where the bottleneck is as it pertains to this function.

---

Edit update:

On (1), it is NOT true that a debug build with the said compiler options optimizes the loop invariant. I was wrong. On deeper digging, it turns out that the function is indeed called twice.

Comment: The C++ compiler might inline the indirection that you think is in (2). So there may not actually be a price to pay.

Comment: To answer (3), if it is not the bottleneck, why bother? If you use a statistical profiler like gprof, you'll likely never see the code being called. So I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: The call to `size()` *may* be inlined and *may* be performed only once. But I don't see anything in the standard that *guarantees* you this. But, if you use a range-for loop, then you *are guaranteed* that `.size()` will be evaluated only once.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend Is it not the case that any member function that is defined in the declaration (i.e., header file) itself automatically inlined? Your comment indicates that even that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Examples in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for seem to be only for raw vectors/arrays that are publicly accessible. Is it possible to use range-for via member functions as specified in OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loop calls a non constant method on the vector then I’d pretty much say with certainty that all bets are off.

If you only call const methods on the vector then you could hope for optimisations, but since the standard does not require them, you can’t really blame a compiler for not making an optimisation that may appear obvious to you,

Given that you can declare more than one variable in the for loop so long as they are of the same type, bringing sz into the loop seems the obvious thing to do. Or, can you run the loop backwards?

Comment: Yes, what goes on within the loop does not alter the vector. But only I know that. The compiler need not. So, it seems that there is no guarantee of optimization. I cannot possibly run the loop backward -- I see how that might help. If we go forward, it seems `sz` is the only guaranteed way.

Comment: @Tryer: Indeed, that’s the gist of it.